# Network request failed with fetch and expo?

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

In a new expo app I wrote actions identical to a normal react-native app but they do not work.

In the past fetch worked just fine on non expo apps.

```
const f = await fetch(
    `${server}/u/login/app`,
    {
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: login,
        password,
      }),
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
    }
  );
```

I expected to get a 200 response with a json object.
Instead it throws

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror
```